# Python function with a lot of arguments

Tags: python

I am new to Python and higher level languages in general, so I was wondering if it is looked down upon if I have a function that takes in a lot of arguments, and how to better architect my code to prevent this.

For example what this function is essentially doing is printing each location of a string in a file.

```
def scan(fpin,base,string,pNo,print_to_file,dumpfile_path,quiet):
```

This function is being called from the main function, which is basically parsing the command line arguments and passing the data to the scan function. I have thought of creating a class containing all of these arguments and passing it to scan,but there will only be one instance of this data, so wouldn't that be pointless?

Comment: Aside from all good solutions mentioned below you can also think about refactoring your function. If it is taking so many arguments perhaps it is also doing a lot of different things? Perhaps you can isolate and abstract some of those procedures into different functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Named arguments are your friends. For things that act like semi-optional configuration options with reasonable defaults, give the parameters the defaults, and only pass them (as named arguments) for non-default situations. If there are a lot of parameters without reasonable defaults, then you may want to name all of them when you call the function.

Consider the built-in function `sorted`. It takes up to four arguments. Is the `reverse` parameter before or after `cmp`? What should I pass in as `key` if I want the default behavor? Answer: Hell if I can remember. I call `sorted(A, reverse=True)` and it does what I'd expect.

Incidentally, if I had a ton of "config"-style arguments that I was passing into every call to scan, and only changing (say, `fpin` and `string`) each time, I might be inclined to put all the other argumentsinto a dictionary, and then pass it to the function with `**kwargs` syntax. That's a little more advanced. See the manual for details. (Note that this is NOT the same as declaring the function as taking `**kwargs`. The function definition is the same, the only difference is what calls to it look like.)

Answer (score 2):

No, there's really nothing wrong with it. If you have N different arguments (things that control the execution of your function), you have to pass them somehow - how you actually do that is just user preference if you ask me.

However... if you find yourself doing something like this, though:

```
func('somestring', a=A, b=B, c=C)
func('something else', a=A, b=B)
func('something third', a=A, c=C, d=D)
```

etc. where A,B,C are really configurations for lots of different things, then you should start looking into a class. A class does many things, but it does also create context. Instead, then you can do something like:

```
cf = myclass(a=A, b=B, c=C, d=D)
cf.func('somestring')
cf.func('something else')
cf.func('something third')
```

etc.